VS Code не видит Python
Мой VS Code не видит интерпретатор Python. При запуске файла появляется надпись в правом углу: выберите интерпретатор. Нажимаю на неё, открывается список, но там моего интерпретатора нет. Что делать? Пробовал несколько раз переустанавливать пайтон и VS Code, не помогло. Ниже прикрепляю скриншот. Что делать?


попробовать переустановить VS Code. Если проблема не устранена, посмотреть логи View -> Output.

Просто вручную путь к интерпретатору укажите через файловый менеджер. самый первый пункт выпадающего меню.
